# Using setTimeout() pause a Mocha test

Tags: mocha.js

I'm using Mocha to write tests for a Node API. In one test, I need to execute 2 actions and compare the timestamp of each and ensure that they are different. To do that, I need to reliably pause the test execution for at least a second. I was trying to use `setTimeout` to pause the Mocha execution before the second call to `ping`, but it's not happening.

```
it( 'should insert then update the timestamp.', function( done ) {
  Do.ping( 'arg1', function( err, result ) {
    should.not.exist( err );

    setTimeout( Do.ping( 'arg1', function( err, result ) {
      // Test that the timestamp of the first ping is before the timestamp
      // of the second ping (among other things)
      done();
    }), 1000 );
  });
});
```

Anyone see what I've borked here? Alternatively, is there a better (i.e. more Mocha-ish) way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Sinon's fake timer API and it's been working great. Instantiate and reset the fake timer in `beforeEach()` and `afterEach()`, respectively. Within the actual test, just advance the clock in whatever way you need:

```
clock.tick( 180000 ); // Advances the JS clock 3 minutes (180 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest an (untested) alternative:

```
var async = require('async')
it( 'should insert then update the timestamp.', function( done ) {
  async.series([
  Do.ping( 'arg1', function( err, result ) {
    should.not.exist( err );
  },
  setTimeout(console.log('waiting'),1000);
  },
  Do.ping( 'arg2', function( err, result ) {
    should.not.exist( err );
  },
  done();]
  });
});
```

I think by using async.series you'll be able to more reliably pause mocha from getting to the second call.

Comment: Thanks. I've been trying out the sinon package for manipulating the JS clock and so far that's been working out pretty well.

Answer (score -1):

I've added the `sleepfor` package using `npm install sleepfor`. In my test I have the following:

```
const sleepfor = require('sleepfor');

describe('My Test', function() {
    it('should test something here.', function(){
        // Run some test code here.
    });
    it('should test something ELSE here.', function(){
        // Run different test code here.
    });

    afterEach(function(){
        var d = new Date();
        console.log(d.toLocaleString() + " >> Before sleep.");
        sleepfor(5000);

        var d = new Date();
        console.log(d.toLocaleString() + " >> After sleep.");
    });
});
```

Should be obvious, but just in case, `afterEach` is called after each of your it block executions.

Comment: It is much better to use the method in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18000251/1906307) than use something like `sleepfor`. Each test will *necessarily* take at least 5 seconds to run. Start adding tests to the suite and soon you're spending minutes waiting. Now, do the same test by manipulating the clock, and the test will take milliseconds to run. Moreover `sleepfor` does not really "sleep": it runs a loop during the interval you ask. So your process will eat your CPU during that time: a waste of resources! Again, manipulating the clock avoids this issue.

Comment: Yep, I misunderstood the question. I came across this question from searching how to pause/sleep in between tests. I'd also add that in my case I finally ended up just using the `browser.pause(...)`. Suited me well, but as @Louis points out, it is not the answer to this question.